# apache web-flow. The flow doesn't start

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-webflow-2

i have created a very simple project to study the apache webflow. I have created a configuration file for spring and webflow as well. There is only one `OrderController`, but it doesn't work. I can call the first site of project, but when i click on link to start workflow (`Buy books`), there is only error `HTTP Status 404`

Me is very strange, why the web-flow doesn't start. I have declared in the configuration file the `flowExecuter`, `flowRegistry`, `MvcViewFactoryCreator` with reference to `apache-tiles`. I have no idea what more to do and ask for help and assist.

the project is `tutorial.spring-webflow` and is in [gitgub](https://github.com/oleg-duvanayev/common.issues.git)

many thanks

Answer (score 0):

the issue solved. The reason is

1. absent of FlowHandlerMapping and FlowHandlerAdapter
2. **It is the most important**: The location of web-flow configuration file and call the webflow from browser. I am reading a book `Pro Spring MVC with Web Flow`. In the book the author places the webflow configuration file together with `jsp` and calls it from browser as `localhost:8080/[myapplication]/createOrder`. It is don't work for me and it was the main reason of error. I don't know why.

Finally i placed my workflow configuration file separate to other folder. It look like this:

```js
<webflow:flow-registry id="flowRegistry" base-path="/WEB-INF/flows" 
 flow-builder-services="flowBuilderServices">     
        <webflow:flow-location-pattern value="/**/*-flow.xml" />
</webflow:flow-registry>
```

> WEB-INF 
>   ++++flows 
>   +++++++ ordering 
>   ++++++++++++++order 
>   ++++++++++++++++++createOrder-flow.xml

the call from browser look like this:

> http//localhost:8080/[myapplication]/ordering/order

and it works

Now i would like to inform me, what for the call from browser must to be by having

> WEB-INF 
>   ++++flows 
>   +++++++ ordering 
>   ++++++++++++++createOrder-flow.xml

i would suppose

> http//localhost:8080/[myapplication]/ordering/createOrder 
>   http//localhost:8080/[myapplication]/createOrder

but both doesn't work